# After removing graphics card GRUB has problems

Tags: debian, grub2

I freshly installed Debian stretch with a broken radeon hd 7970. It was a standard installation with selecting nothing, but the SSH server. I didn't do any settings except giving it a static IP. on reboot with graphics card i saw the login screen and tried connecting to it over SSH and it worked.
Then I removed the graphics card and started it, but i couldn't establish a connection over SSH. My router tells me that that machine is not connected to the network. I had the same scenario a while ago with the same hardware and it worked.
What I tried was:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

So the fact that I hear the "GRUB_INIT_TUNE" tells me the pc itself has no problems without graphics.
CPU is Intel Q9550 so there is no integrated graphics.

I have a feeling, that it has something to do with the DRM (Directed Rendering Manager).

Comment: boot to console https://superuser.com/questions/1088054/how-to-boot-to-command-line-interface-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @MichaelD.
`Unit display-manager.service could not be found.`
It seems like I don't have it installed.
After doing:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`
it still doesnt work

Comment: AFAIK Gnome Desktop runs GDM as display manager, KDE sddm. Depending on your Desktop env you need to check LXDM, XDM, LightDM, slim, ...

Comment: @MichaelD. the thing is since i only choose SSH server at the installation, i would say I dont have any DE. My next step is trying to figure out how I can make dmesg log.

Comment: Ok. I fixed it. The problem was caused by the new interface naming since Debian stretch. kern.log with graphics card: `sky2 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: renamed from eth0`. kern.log without graphics card: `sky2 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: renamed from eth0` so changing enp2s0 to enp1s0 in /etc/network/interfaces fixed it.